# Centering custom checkbox

Tags: css

I'm trying to vertically/horizontally center a CSS checkmark (`span:after`) within a custom checkbox (`span:before`), and add a 1em margin to the right of said box, but what I've tried isn't having the desired effect.

CSS:

```
form label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form label:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 60px;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 2ex;
  width: 2ex;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-right: 3em;
}
form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.2ex;
  height: 0.4ex;
  background: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0.4ex;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/qRMLQR)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/n81o394s/).

```
form label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form label:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 60px;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-120%);
  height: 2ex;
  width: 2ex;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-right: 3em;
}
form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.2ex;
  height: 0.4ex;
  background: transparent;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-250%);
  left: -0.1ex;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't feel exact. I'm also trying to add a margin in between the checkbox and text label. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity of the checkbox to `0` instead of `display: none`, set the pseudo element to `left: 0` and set a margin to the `input`:

```css
form label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form label:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 60px;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
form input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 2ex;
  width: 2ex;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* margin-right: 3em; */
}
form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
form input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.2ex;
  height: 0.4ex;
  background: transparent;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0.4ex;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="search-site-filter" value="option1" required>
    <span>Checkbox label</span>
  </label>
</form>
```